# Need to convert this curl to Google apps script Urlfetch

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

I’m trying to convert this curl to Google apps script but I’m getting 400 bad request

Here’s the curl command

```
curl --include \
     --header "Authorization: Basic YXBpLXVzZXJuYW1lOmFwaS1wYXNzd29yZA=="  \
     --request POST \
     --header "Content-Type: application/json" \

     --data-binary "    {
        \"messages\":[
            {
                \"source\":\"php\",
                \"body\":\"Jelly liquorice marshmallow candy carrot cake 4Eyffjs1vL.\",
                \"to\":\"+61411111111\"
            },
            {
                \"source\":\"php\",
                \"body\":\"Chocolate bar icing icing oat cake carrot cake jelly cotton MWEvciEPIr.\",
                \"to\":\"+61422222222\"
            }
        ]
    }" \
'https://rest.clicksend.com/v3/sms/send'
```

Comment: Show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to convert the curl command in your question to Google Apps Script.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  const url = "https://rest.clicksend.com/v3/sms/send";
  const params = {
    method: "post",
    headers: { Authorization: "Basic YXBpLXVzZXJuYW1lOmFwaS1wYXNzd29yZA==" },
    contentType: "application/json",
    payload: JSON.stringify({
      "messages": [
        {
          "body": "Jelly liquorice marshmallow candy carrot cake 4Eyffjs1vL.",
          "source": "php",
          "to": "+61411111111"
        },
        {
          "body": "Chocolate bar icing icing oat cake carrot cake jelly cotton MWEvciEPIr.",
          "source": "php",
          "to": "+61422222222"
        }
      ]
    })
  };
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  console.log(res.getContentText());
}
```

#### Note:

- In this sample script, it supposes that your curl command works fine. Please be careful this.
- If you want to see the response header, you can also use `getAllHeaders()`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response#getallheaders)

#### Reference:

- [UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)